Is it okay to submit another paper to the same journal while the first one is still under review (within a short span such as of 3 months)?
About 3 months ago, I submitted a paper to a journal, say journal X. There hasn't been any news on that from the journal, i.e. that paper is currently under review. Now for my current work, which I have just finished writing, I find that journal X will again be the most well-suited choice. So while one of my papers is still under review, is it okay to submit another paper to the same journal (within a short span such as of 3 months) or should I consider some other journal?

Is there a reason you think this might not be okay?

@Aruralreader I was told by my seniors that such a thing apparently is not perceived well!

I did this by writing up my masters work and then the first part of my PhD. In the end, both papers were accepted and ended up coming out in the same issue of the journal! :-)

Yes, it is fine. There are no conventions about this. Depending on the journal's workload in a particular area and the available reviewers, it might take a bit longer than otherwise, but the editors will be able to deal with it.
And, while you should also consider other journals, the best one in your judgement should be where you submit to.
One aspect, though, is whether the new paper would be considered an advance sufficient to make the earlier one less "novel" assuming they overlap in key ideas. In that case, it might be better to wait or submit elsewhere.

Actually the two papers are of two different areas.

This is uncommon enough that it might raise eyebrows if it's noticed, but there's nothing organically wrong with it.
Perhaps the biggest practical difference with "normal" peer review is that there's a higher chance that the same editor will handle both your papers, but from the perspective of the author, there's still nothing you need to do different.
